# Using move semantic to push element into two containers

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I have recently read about moving semantics and rvalue reference.

Having a class that has 2 containers of pointers to the struct. e.g

```
struct Person{
   Person(int i , int a){
      id  = i;
      age = a
   }
   Person(Person && p){
       id  = p.id;
       age = p.id;
   }
   int id;
   int age;
}
class Holder{

 private:
   vector<Person*> one;
   vector<Person*> two;
}
```

Both containers should recieve same Person , however , one should be sorted by age and another by id. I could do something like

```
void Person::Insert( int age , int id ){
    Person* tmp = new Person(age , id );
    one.push_back(tmp);
    // sort somehow one .. isnt important for this example
    two.push_back(tmp);
    // same sort
}
```

But could it be improved using r-value reference and moving semantic? Would it actually make the step faster / better memory cost? And first of all would it make sense to do it? e.g

```
   void Person::Insert(Person*&& p){
       one.push_back(p);
       // sort
       two.push_back(p);
       // sort?   
}
```

I appreciate all explanation of concept in case i misunderstood move semantic.

Comment: No, it wouldn't be. For starters, you're not pushing the same object into the two vectors, you're pushing a pointer to the object. So whatever move semantics are implemented for `Person`, it will make no difference whatsoever. You're pushing a pointer, not an object, into the two vectors.

Comment: The type of the item you operate on during original `one.push_back(tmp);` is `Person*`. A pointer. You will not get any improvement. Moving/copying pointers is as fast as moving/copying integers. Actually **move** may be a little slower since it **may** need to **copy-and-clear-the-source**. whereas copy would just copy.

Comment: does it need to be Holder::insert in place of Person::insert?